# phantomjsdriver how to add user-agent?

Tags: c#, selenium, nuget, phantomjs, nuget-package

i'm using phantomjsdriver 1.8.1 for .net (C#) 
 http://www.nuget.org/packages/phantomjs.exe/ and wonder how to add user-agent firefox before loading the web content

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although Cybermax's answer is somewhat correct, it isn't correct in terms of what you are actually using - C#. To specify a user agent for the `PhantomJSDriver` in C#, you will need to give it as an "additional capability":

```
var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
```

These options should be passed into the constructor used to create the driver:

```
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
```

To verify this has been set correctly, you can check against a website that tells you the user agent of your browser, something like [WhatIsMyUserAgent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) or look closely at the PhantomJS console window, it'll have a "useragent" value there, and you should see it's been set to what you specified above.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you have to define property [page.settings.userAgent](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) before the first call to page.open.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'; //firefox 25
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function (status) {
  // do something
});
```

Note : the last version of PhantomJS is 1.9.2. Another package is available [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhantomJS/).